# Is it possible to add a custom dialog for Moving Files when creating a custom IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am developing my own IntelliJ plugin and when I try to move a file, a dialog pops up.

Sometimes, the checkbox "Search for references" is deselected and I would like to have it selected every time a user of my plugin tries to move a certain file.

Do i need to create a custom `MoveFilesOrDirectoriesDialog` or is there a simpler way to implement this?

- I looked up the Jetbrains guide to make my own plugin, found a post about making my own Renaming Dialog, but couldn't find anything related to a Moving Dialog.
- I tried to implement a `MoveFilesOrDirectoriesProcessor` but there is no way to include this class in my plugin.xml
- I have implemented a `MoveHandler` but its methods are invoked after the dialog pops up
- I have implemented a  `MoveFilesOrDirectoriesHandler` (call it `ClassA`) which uses the `MoveFilesOrDirectoriesUtil$doMove` method. In this method, the dialog is built. The only problem is that this class is final, meaning that I cannot edit this class nor its methods.
- My last option was to copy all of the methods from `MoveFilesOrDirectoriesUtil` into `ClassA` but it was no help either, since the `MoveFilesOrDirectoriesDialog` uses private fields, which I don't have access to